# SwiftUI half modal view not allowing text field on parent view to be tapped on

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have built a half modal view that is used to display filters on a searchable list. The parent view has a text field that users can enter a search term in, and then a button will activate the half modal view to pop up for further functionality. The modal view works good, but I have now noticed that I can't enter text into the search field even when the modal is not actived... If I comment out the modal view then the text field works again.

Has anyone encountered this problem or know why it may be happening?

I have attached code here so you can see:

```swift
var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            TextField("Search for Receipts", text: $searchInput, onCommit: {runSearch = true})
                .overlay(
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.leading, 8)
                        
                        if isEditing {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.searchInput = ""
                                self.isEditing = false
                                self.runSearch = false
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .padding(.trailing, 8)
                            }
                        }
                 
                    }
                )
                .onTapGesture {
                    isEditing  = true
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    
            if !runSearch {
                List{
                    ForEach(searchResults, id: \.self) { shop in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.searchInput = shop
                            self.runSearch = true
                        }, label: {
                            Text("\(shop)")
                        })
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //Run search functionality here
            }
            
            
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("SEARCH", displayMode: .inline)
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.showFilter.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
//Placement of the half modal sheet
        .halfSheet(showSheet: $showFilter) {
            FilterView(PriceLowHigh: $PriceLowHigh, PriceHighLow: $PriceHighLow, mostRecent: $mostRecent, byDate: $byDate, runSearch: $runSearch, dateFrom: $dateFrom, dateTo: $dateTo, closeFilter: $showFilter)
        } onEnd: {
            print("Dismiss")
        }

        
    }

}
```

And the code for the half modal:

```swift
//Creating a half modal view to display the filter options
extension View {
    
    func halfSheet<SheetView: View>(showSheet: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder sheetView: @escaping () ->SheetView, onEnd: @escaping()->())-> some View {
        
        return self
            .overlay(
                HalfSheetHelper(sheetView: sheetView(), showSheet: showSheet, onEnd: onEnd)
            )
    }
}

//UIKit extension
struct HalfSheetHelper<SheetView: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var sheetView: SheetView
    let controller = UIViewController()
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool
    var onEnd: ()->()
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        
        controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        if showSheet {
            
            let sheetController = CustomHostingController(rootView: sheetView)
            sheetController.presentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
            
            uiViewController.present(sheetController, animated: true)
        } else {
            uiViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    class Coordinator:NSObject, UISheetPresentationControllerDelegate {
        var parent: HalfSheetHelper
        
        init(parent: HalfSheetHelper) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
            parent.showSheet = false
            parent.onEnd()
        }
    }
    
}

class CustomHostingController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content>{
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        //setting presentation controller properties
        if let presentationController = presentationController as? UISheetPresentationController {
            presentationController.detents = [
                .medium()
                //.large()
            ]
            
            presentationController.prefersGrabberVisible = true
            presentationController.preferredCornerRadius = 5.0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `overlay` modifier by a `.background()` :

```
.background(
    HalfSheetHelper(sheetView: sheetView(), showSheet: showSheet, onEnd: onEnd)
)
```

This will solve the problem of TextFields and Buttons which are not clickable when the HalfSheet is not presented.

You still won't be able to enter any text when the HalfSheet is presented: but this is how `UISheetPresentationController` works if you let the noninteractive dimming view underneath the sheet. When we click outside the modal it is dismissed. If you want to change this behaviour, you can change the `smallestUndimmedDetentIdentifier`.

## Edit :

You will still have a problem: when your view is going to be dismissed, `updateUIViewController` will be called again and the HalfSheet will be presented again (and dismissed again because `showSheet == false`).
You need some logic to prevent it from being presented again. For example, <s>we can use `presentationControllerWillDismiss`</s> @Philip's proposal and check if the half sheet was presented :

```
struct HalfSheetHelper<SheetView: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var sheetView: SheetView
    let controller = UIViewController()
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool
    var onEnd: ()->()
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        let presenting = uiViewController.presentedViewController != nil
        if showSheet && !presenting {
            let sheetController = CustomHostingController(rootView: sheetView)
            sheetController.presentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
            uiViewController.present(sheetController, animated: true)
        } else if !showSheet && presenting {
            uiViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    class Coordinator:NSObject, UISheetPresentationControllerDelegate {
        var parent: HalfSheetHelper
        init(parent: HalfSheetHelper) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
            self.parent.showSheet = false
            self.parent.onEnd()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what causes recomposition in your case, because before `showSheet` is set to false nothing should cause a recomposition with current code. Yet your point is correct in case if using state variables inside `halfSheet`. And you don't need to create a `State` variable, because you can check if it was presented with `let presenting = uiViewController.presentedViewController != nil`, so `if showSheet && !presenting { present } else if !showSheet && presenting { dismiss }`

Comment: @Philip : when the modal is dismissed (for example if the user taps outside) `updateUIViewController` is always called.
The order is `presentationControllerWillDismiss`, then `updateUIViewController`, and finally `presentationControllerDidDismiss`

Comment: @Philip : about your second point: your proposal is better, i'm updating my answer, thanks.

Comment: `updateUIViewController` is not called in my sample and it shouldn't: it's part of SwiftUI lifecycle and it gets called when one of `@State`/`@Binding`/etc variables changes. UIKit lifecycle events can't trigger it. You're triggering it call when settings `showSheet` to `false` in `willDismiss`, it should be in `didDismiss` like it was in question authors code.

Comment: @Philip : in my sample `updateUIViewController` is always called on dismiss. I can even remove the Coordinator and it's the same :)

Comment: @Philip : Again with author's code, if we remove the dimming view (setting `smallestUndimmedDetentIdentifier` to `.large`), this behaviour change and  `updateUIViewController` is no longer called on dismiss.